# Tensorflow: Using output vector as input in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, type-conversion

I have some set of operations, that was processed already:

```
auto net1 = ops::ReadFile(scope, filename);
auto net2 = ops::DecodePng(scope, net1);

std::vector<Tensor> outputs1;
session.Run({ net2 }, &outputs1);
```

Now I have to use an `output` vector as an input for new operation set:

```
auto net3 = ?????
auto net4 = ops::Cast(scope, net3, DT_FLOAT);

std::vector<Tensor> outputs2;
session.Run({ net4 }, &outputs2);
```

The question is: How do I convert std::vector to tensorflow::Input? Is there any build-in method for it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Tensor as an input:

```
auto net3 = outputs1[0]
```

This works ok in my case, because I have only one image.